# SetupWithNavController does't work for toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, androidx

I am trying to bind toolbar to navigation controller, for that I am using the following code:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host))
```

and in the menu file, I provided the id of the fragment to which app should navigate like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

and I have a simple navigation graph file like this:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.vapoyan.myapplication.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_menuFragment"
            app:destination="@id/menuFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:name="com.vapoyan.myapplication.MenuFragment"
        android:label="fragment_menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" />
</navigation>
```

Does anyone have experience or can suggest how I can fix the issue and is toolbar supported by the navigation component?

Any example code or reference?

Answer (score 13):

Finally, I found a solution thanks to [Google CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#8)

What I was missing was:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
     return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host))
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Plus if you want to have back button support you need in `onCreate` method to add:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host))
```

Basically, In my understanding just bt providing `id` of the correct fragment for the menu item and calling `setupWithNavController` should work, but that assumption was not correct, or maybe in the current version (**1.0.0-alpha07**) Google guys changed something. So now it is working fine.

If you see that there is a way to do it shorter :) or better :) let me know.

Comment: It is a side mention in the docs but the default behavior is for menu navigation with `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()` to wipe your backstack. To fix this you need to set `android:menuCategory="secondary"` on the menu items XML

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the above answer.  Make sure the id's for both the navigation and item match.

```
android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
```

I got hung up on this because I had separate id's for each element.

Comment: Thanks very much! This isn't seem to have been documented.

Comment: Many Thanks tzg, You make my day.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Navigation drawer in my app, but i think this will be enough for ur case:

At this moment i am using this android libs:
In my build.gradle

```
 implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha07'
 implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha07'
```

In my Activity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, /*ur nav controller ID*/)

        // Set up ActionBar
        setSupportActionBar(/*ur toolbar*/)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }
}
```

U can check the docs here u can find more info: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar

Comment: I found a solution I was missing call to

`override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
     return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host))
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}`

Answer (score 0):

For people using Kotlin, refer to this documentation link - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar

1. Define a toolbar in MainActivity.xml -

```
<LinearLayout>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        ... />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Call setupWithNavController() in MainActivity.kt `onCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```