# BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Currently I'm developing an Android app, in which I would like to utilize both `Android Navigation Component` and `BottomNavigationView`.

While working on said app I checked out **the official codelab** and several questions here, but they didn't prove to be of any help.

The problem is that assigning `navController` to my `BottomNavigationView` does not seem to have any effect - clicking on menu items does not affect the navigation host.

**My code:**

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_host_fr"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_bnv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.aredruss.qurio.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.aredruss.qurio.helpers.viewBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ViewBindingDelegate
    private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by viewBinding(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    }

    // Using onPostCreate because accessing NavHost in OnCreate causes crashes
    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        binding.navigationBb.setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.main_host_fr))
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.mainNavBnv, findNavController(R.id.main_host_fr))
    }
}
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/action_history">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_history"
        android:name="com.aredruss.qurio.ui.HistoryFragment"
        android:label="HistoryFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_history" >
    </fragment>
  
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:name="com.aredruss.qurio.ui.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="SettingsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_history"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
        android:title="History"
        app:showAsAction="withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        app:showAsAction="withText"
        />
</menu>
```

I've checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443965/setupwithnavcontroller-doest-work-for-toolbar/53444133) solution and it wasn't of any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've overridden the wrong `onPostCreate()`:

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
```

You don't want the one that takes a `PersistableBundle` - you want the regular one:

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```

Now your `onPostCreate()` will actually be called.

Of course, you shouldn't be using `onPostCreate()` at all. Instead, you should be [following the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate), which specifically state that you should be using the following code to get your `NavController` in `onCreate()`:

```
val navHostFragment =
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_host_fr) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

which lets you write your entire code as:

```
// ViewBindingDelegate
private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by viewBinding(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Note how we actually set the content view from the binding
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_host_fr) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    binding.navigationBb.setupWithNavController(navController)
    binding.mainNavBnv.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it also proved to be helpful.

Comment: I'm also marking your answer as the solution, thanks again

Comment: What is `navigationBb` in this?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl - that's the `android:id` of the `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: I thought that was `mainNavBnv`

Answer (score 4):

Here are the concerns that need to be fixed:

- You are using `ViewBindingDelegate` which automatically handles the `setContentView`, so you need to remove this, as you won't be able to use `binding.xx` in this case:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //<<<<< remove this
    
}
```

- You [use `onPostCreate` while it should not be implemented by developers, and only need to be touched by the system](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

> Called when activity start-up is complete (after onStart() and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) have been called). Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final initialization after application code has run.

As per my test, `onPostCreate()` didn't get called. So, to fix this, move this part of code to a lifecycle method that can be implemented by developers like `onStart()` or `onResume()`:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
        binding.mainNavBnv,
        findNavController(R.id.main_host_fr)
    )
}
```

This way the `NavController` can auto handle the `BottomNavigationView`:

**UPDATE**: As per comments, you should get the `NavController` using the NavHostFragment as follows, and therefore you can transfer the code to the `onCreate()` method:

```
val navHostFragment =
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_host_fr) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It did fix my issue, although I need to mention that the implementation of `ViewBindingDelegate` which I'm using [this one](https://gist.github.com/gmk57/aefa53e9736d4d4fb2284596fb62710d) does require a call to `setContentView`, but with binding.root as the argument, not the layout itself.
Implementing `OnPostCreate` was something I tried looking through StackOv.

Comment: Note that calling `setupWithNavController` in either `onPostCreate()` or `onStart()` isn't necessary or recommended, as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate) and my answer below.

Comment: @AlexanderMedyanik Welcome.. Please have a look at [this](https://proandroiddev.com/viewbinding-with-kotlin-property-delegate-c907682e24c9) one; it doesn't require a call to `setContentView()`

Comment: Note that when using the delegate linked to by @Zain, you cannot put any code that is reliant on your view in your Activity's `onCreate()` method (as it relies on a `LifecycleObserver`, which only gets its callback after `onCreate()`) - you'd also want to use your own `LifecycleObserver` in that case (which will automatically ordered after the delegate if the `init` block you add your LifecycleObserver in is after your delegate declaration) and **also** not use `onPostCreate()` or `onStart()`. That's probably more work than you'd save, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

that issue happens when making an incorrect import Toolbar So firstly, try to remove the Tool Bar import And Add that line to the Bar import

androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar Android X Toolbar