# Cannot resolve method 'setupWithNavController(NavController)'

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I implement a single-activity architecture with flow fragments in Java. My `MainFlowFragment` is where I setup bottom navigation view with 4 fragments inside this flow.

MainFlowFragment.java:

```
package kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import kz.rating.onaikazakh.R;
import kz.rating.onaikazakh.databinding.FlowFragmentMainBinding;

public class MainFlowFragment extends Fragment {

    private NavController navController=null;
    private FlowFragmentMainBinding binding;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flow_fragment_main, container, false);



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        /*Fragment navHostFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_main);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(navHostFragment, R.id.nav_host_fragment_main);*/
        BottomNavigationView bnv = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_main);
        navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        NavGraph navGraph = navController.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.main_graph);
        /*AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_grammar, R.id.navigation_texts, R.id.navigation_vocabulary, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController((AppCompatActivity)getActivity(), navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bnv, navController);*/

        bnv.setupWithNavController(navController);


        navController.setGraph(navGraph);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

flow_fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wave_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wave" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_grammar"
        android:icon="@drawable/grammar_nav_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_grammar" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_texts"
        android:icon="@drawable/texts_nav_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_texts" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_vocabulary"
        android:icon="@drawable/vocab_nav_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_vocabulary" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_nav_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

</menu>
```

main_graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_grammar">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_grammar"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow.grammar.GrammarFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_grammar"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_show_material_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_texts"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow.texts.TextsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_texts"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_show_material_list" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_vocabulary"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow.vocabulary.VocabularyFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_vocabulary"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_vocabulary" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

</navigation>
```

App level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kz.rating.onaikazakh"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }


}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android.useAndroidX=true` is set in gradle.properties

What I have tried:

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602841/bottomnavigationview-setupwithnavcontroller-not-working) and tried both in onCreateView and onViewCreated.
I tried to update all dependencies to the latest versions, and also to the versions from other answers on the topic.
I tried *Invalidate Cache*. None of these worked.

I also tried setting up with NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bnv, navController). In this case, it shows the bottomNavView and main flow, however no fragments are inflated.

Does anyone know how to fix that? Or is there another way to bind navController to bottomNavView within a flow fragment in Java?

**Update**

Thanks to [Sohaib Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20440272/sohaib-ahmed), it worked with NavigationUI.setupWithNavController. I forgot changing properties after moving the block from Constraint to Frame layout. However, the original question is still relevant, so it would be beneficial if anyone knows why this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your height to `match_parent`

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph" />
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```